# Question about a bungee jump problem relating weight to spring constant

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, energy, spring

In the following solution to the bungee jump problem below there is a part that I don't understand. In the middle it says that we can eliminate the weight $mg$ from the fact that the rope extended from $L_0$ to $L$ when the jumper was suspended from it since this implies that $mg=k(L-L_0)$. But I can't see how this equation holds. I would greatly appreciate an explanation to this.

The problem is stated as follows: A bungee jump is planned from a bridge of height $H$. An elastic rope of unstretched length $L_0$ is chosen. The rope stretches to a length $L$ when a bungee jumper is suspended from it while at rest.

Show that the bungee jumper will be safe to jump provided that $$H>L+\sqrt{L^2 - L_0^2},$$ if the sole safety consideration is to avoid contact with the ground using energy conservation and assuming that the rope behaves like a spring when stretched; use the information about the stretched length to relate the jumper's mass to the spring constant $k$ describing the force exerted by the rope.

Solution. Take the bridge to define the zero-point of gravitational potential energy then at the start the rope is unstretched and the jumper not moving, so the total energy $E=0$. Assume that the jumper falls a distance $D$ before being stopped by the elastic rope. Conserving energy, using $U=kx^2/2$ for the rope, and $mgh$ for the gravitational potential, $$E=\frac{1}{2}k(D-L_0)^2-mgD=0. $$**The weight $mg$ can be eliminated using the fact that the rope extended from $L_0$ to $L$ when the jumper was suspended from it, which implies $$mg=K(L-L_0),$$** and thus $$\frac{1}{2}k(D-L_0)^2=kD(L-L_0).$$Thus $$(D-L_0)^2=2D(L-L_0)$$and $$D^2-2DL_0+L_0^2DL-2DL_0,$$ giving $$D^2-2LD+L_0^2=0.$$ This is a quadratic for $D$ with solutions $$D=L\pm \sqrt{L^2-L_0^2}.$$
Only the positive root is of interest we want $D<H,$ hence the final result.

Comment: Please [do not post images of texts you want to quote](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/10563), but type it out instead so it is readable for all users and so that it can be indexed by search engines. For formulae, use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020) instead.

Comment: @Amit I wasn't aware of this. I put it in typed it out now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

It follows from a force equilibrium of restoring Hooke force $F_H$ and weight :

$$ F_H - mg = 0 \tag 1$$, since jumper is suspended at rest. Putting problem definitions here gives :

$$ k(L-L_0) - mg = 0 \tag 2$$, so we can re-define weight as a force by how much it is able to expand rope :

$$ mg = k(L-L_0) \tag 3 $$

Equation (3) is further substituted into potential energies equilibrium to get the final result.